# Grouping by Week giving inaccurate results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all my sales from a table and group them by each week but I am getting the wrong week range.

**table structure**

```
order_id,  sell_price, buy_price, time
```

**Sales per Day**

```
Sell Price   Fees     Buy_Price    Margin   Date
181.98       36.39    78.43        67.154   03-12-2012
65.49        13.08    30.34        22.052   02-12-2012
44.21        8.84     19.45        15.918   29-11-2012
84.46        16.89    32.39        35.178   27-11-2012
106.52       21.30    61.66        23.556   26-11-2012
113.92       22.78    44.74        46.396   25-11-2012
64.74        12.94    26.32        25.472   24-11-2012
16.11        3.22     4.20         8.688    23-11-2012
13.81        2.76     3.62         7.428    22-11-2012
```

**Sales per Week**

```
Sell Price   Fees     Buy_Price    Margin   Date
247.47       49.494   108.77       89.206   03-12-2012
349.11       69.822   158.24       121.048  26-11-2012
94.66        18.932   34.14        41.588   24-11-2012
```

The problem with last table as you may have noticed is that the figures don't add up, the first row should be calculating results from the `3-11-2012 to present` (which means the margin should be 67), while the 2nd should be calculating results from the `26-11-12 to 2-11-12` (which means the margin should be around 95).

The query I am using is below, what could possibly the problem with it as I can not see one.

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
ROUND(SUM(sell_price),2) AS sell_price, 
ROUND(SUM(buy_price/100*20),2) AS fees, 
ROUND(SUM(buy_price),2) AS buy_price, 
ROUND(SUM(sell_price/100*80 - buy_price),2) AS margin, 
time 
FROM order_items 
GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) 
ORDER BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too easy. The week in your instance of mysql starts from Sunday. You want it calculated from Monday. You need to pass a second parameter to the [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function. In your case it will be 1 (I think). However, I recommend you to adjust the [default_week_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format) system variable to match your country's Regional Settings.

Comment: I had no idea you could pass other parameters into the WEEK function, thanks

Comment: Please read about different modes of WEEK function. They are very important (and confusing)